# Merge first two lines in specific column

Tags: awk

I have multiple tab delim files where
first line is 6tabsFILENAME

second line is V1      V2      V3      V4      A       B       FST

as in

```
                                                comb12.NCs.genes.fst
V1      V2      V3      V4      A       B       FST
NC_011462.1     17853   28371   CLIC6   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     73261   121925  RUNX1   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     631101  639557  SETD4   0       0       NA
```

I want to either fuse col5 line1 with col5 line2

```
V1      V2      V3      V4      A       B       FSTcomb12.NCs.genes.fst
NC_011462.1     17853   28371   CLIC6   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     73261   121925  RUNX1   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     631101  639557  SETD4   0       0       NA
```

I've tried (in a loop)

```
awk '{ORS=(NR==1?"":"\n")}1 ' file
```

but I get

```
                                                comb12.NCs.genes.fstV1  V2      V3      V4      A       B       FST
NC_011462.1     17853   28371   CLIC6   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     73261   121925  RUNX1   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     631101  639557  SETD4   0       0       NA
```

It fuses the first two lines as in line1line2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the info from line 1 and then unleash it when you get to line 2. After that just let the default action print the lines as they are.

```
$ awk 'NR==1{f = $NF} NR==2{print $0 f} NR>2' file
V1      V2      V3      V4      A       B       FSTcomb12.NCs.genes.fst
NC_011462.1     17853   28371   CLIC6   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     73261   121925  RUNX1   0       0       NA
NC_011462.1     631101  639557  SETD4   0       0       NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following too.

```
awk 'FNR==1{val=$1;next} FNR==2{$0=$0 val} 1' Input_file | column -t
```

Output will be as follows.

```
V1           V2      V3      V4     A  B  FSTcomb12.NCs.genes.fst
NC_011462.1  17853   28371   CLIC6  0  0  NA
NC_011462.1  73261   121925  RUNX1  0  0  NA
NC_011462.1  631101  639557  SETD4  0  0  NA
```